# Python - intersect list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
artist_and_tags = [{u'Yo La Tengo': ['indie', 'indie rock', 'seen live', 'alternative', 'indie pop', 'rock', 'post-rock', 'dream pop', 'shoegaze', 'noise pop', 'folk', 'experimental', 'alternative rock', 'american', 'lo-fi', 'pop', 'new jersey', 'yo la tengo', 'usa', 'noise rock', '90s', 'noise', '00s', 'ambient', 'post-punk', '80s', 'mellow', 'psychedelic', 'hoboken', 'experimental rock', 'singer-songwriter', 'post rock', 'electronic', 'female vocalists', 'alt-country', 'dreamy', 'matador', 'chillout', 'instrumental', 'favorites', 'punk', 'electronica', 'slowcore', 'folk rock', 'new wave', 'jazz', 'eclectic', 'new york', 'emo']}, {u'Radiohead': ['alternative', 'alternative rock', 'rock', 'indie', 'electronic', 'seen live', 'british', 'britpop', 'indie rock', 'experimental', 'radiohead', 'progressive rock', '90s', 'electronica', 'art rock', 'experimental rock', 'post-rock', 'psychedelic', 'uk', 'male vocalists', 'pop', '00s', 'ambient', 'chillout', 'progressive', 'favorites', 'melancholic', 'awesome', 'overrated', 'english', 'beautiful', 'classic rock', 'genius', 'melancholy', 'better than radiohead', 'trip-hop', 'idm', 'indie pop', 'emo']}, {u'Portishead': ['trip-hop', 'electronic', 'female vocalists', 'chillout', 'trip hop', 'alternative', 'electronica', 'seen live', 'downtempo', 'british', 'indie', 'portishead', 'experimental', 'ambient', 'female vocalist', 'alternative rock', '90s', 'lounge', 'mellow', 'bristol', 'jazz', 'psychedelic', 'chill', 'melancholic', 'triphop', 'uk', 'rock', 'bristol sound', 'acid jazz', 'lo-fi']}]
```

which I'm using to get relatedness between artists.

for that, I'm doing:

```
tags0 = set(artist_and_tags[0].values()[0])
tags1 = set(artist_and_tags[1].values()[0])
tags2 = set(artist_and_tags[2].values()[0])
```

then:

```
intersection1 = tags0 & tags1
intersection2 = tags0 & tags2
intersection3 = tags1 & tags2
```

so:

```
print (intersection1, len(intersection1), intersection2, len(intersection), intersection3, len(intersection3))
```

shows me that "Yo La Tengo" is closer to "Radiohead" than "Portishead", with 20 intersected tags.

this code seems a bit redundant, however...

QUESTION:

Is there a way to use this logic in a `for loop` (or wrapped in a simple `function`), so it works with a dictionary with `n` artists(`keys`)?

Comment: You should probably just keep sets as values, no? Unless it needs to be ordered, or maybe you want multiple items?

Comment: `tags0 = set(artist_and_tags[0].values()[0])` -->  `TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Given n artists do you want to find the two most who match, or just all matches?

Comment: all matches, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations`.

```
import itertools
import collections

ArtistTags = collections.namedtuple('ArtistTags', ('name', 'tags'))
tags = (ArtistTags(artist, set(tags))
        for artists_dict in artist_and_tags
        for artist, tags in artists_dict.items())
artist_pairings = itertools.combinations(tags, 2)
intersections = ((len(a.tags & b.tags), a, b) for a, b in artist_pairings)
for n, a, b in sorted(intersections, reverse=True):
    print(n, a.name, b.name)
```

output:

```
20 Yo La Tengo Radiohead
16 Yo La Tengo Portishead
16 Radiohead Portishead
```

Comment: It's a nested list comprehension. It's equivalent to `tags=[];  for artists_dict in artist_and_tags:   for artist, tags in artists_dict.items():  tags.append(ArtistTags(artist, set(tags))`